# JTextField Doesn't Update With Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, jtextfield

I'm trying to figure out why the text field isn't updating. I'm aware that using SwingWorker will probably fix this problem, but I can't understand why it doesn't work in the first place.

```
public class waitExample {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtLeadingText;
private String one = "update string 1";
private String two = "update string 2";
private String three = "update string 3";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                waitExample window = new waitExample();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public waitExample() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    txtLeadingText = new JTextField();
    txtLeadingText.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtLeadingText.setText("leading text");
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtLeadingText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    txtLeadingText.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnClickMeTo = new JButton("CLICK ME TO UPDATE TEXT");
    btnClickMeTo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            try {

                updateOne();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                updateTwo();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                updateThree();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                updateLast();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnClickMeTo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private void updateOne() {

    txtLeadingText.setText(one);
}

private void updateTwo() {

    txtLeadingText.setText(two);
}

private void updateThree() {

    txtLeadingText.setText(three);
}

private void updateLast() {

    txtLeadingText.setText("default text");
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the default Thread will prevent any GUI updates. That shouldn't matter because I am setting the textField BEFORE the Thread.sleep.
Why doesn't the text field update? Shouldn't the text be set, then the Thread wait?

**EDIT:** As per the answers, the above code has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking `Thread.sleep(1000);` on EDT. This means that when your method will end - only then the repaint() will fire (at some point in time later).

Until then your GUI is freezed.

Consider that this is going on one thread (so processing is straightforward):

```
txtLeadingText.setText(one);
Thread.sleep(1000);
txtLeadingText.setText(two);
Thread.sleep(1000);
txtLeadingText.setText(three);
Thread.sleep(1000);
...
<returning from updateText()>
<processing other events on button click>
...
// some time later
<Swing finds out that GUI needs repaint: calls rapaint()>
```

This is what you should do (I didn't compile or test it):

```
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private List<String> strsToSet;
        public MyRunnable(List<String> strsToSet) {
            this.strsToSet = strsToSet;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(strsToSet.size() > 0) {
                    final String str = strsToSet.get(0);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txtLeadingText.setText(str);
                        }
                    });

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    List<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>(strsToSet);
                    newList.remove(0);
                    new Thread(new MyRunnable(newList)).start();
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    new Thread(new MyRunnable(Arrays.asList(one, two, three))).start();
```

It is hard to do in Swing but in contrast in dynamically languages (like Groovy) it would go as simple as that (you'll get a better grasp of what is going on):

```
    edt { 
        textField.setText(one)
        doOutside { 
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            edt {
                textField.setText(two)
                doOutside { 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                    edt {
                        textField.setText(three)
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: To further explain: when you call a function like `txtLeadingText.setText(one)`, the text displayed on the GUI doesn't immediately update. Instead, the internal variable for the text field will change, and it will also notify the Swing Queue that it needs to repaint. Because this goes through the event queue, it only runs through `repaint()` *after* your function returns.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier As per the answer and your comment, I've changed the code (see post). The updated code reflects what I understand from your comments, although it still doesn't fix the error. If  'repaint();'  is called _after_ returning from the method, shouldn't everything update correctly?

Comment: @Aaron this is still executing in the same thread. Now it goes like this: `enter mouseClicked()`->`enter updateOne()`->`exit updateOne()`->`enter ...`->`exit mouseClicked()`->...->`execute repaint()`

Comment: @Xeon So 'repaint()' isn't called until exiting 'mouseClicked()'?

Answer (score 1):

The GUI event loop updates the screen, but it can't update the screen until you return.

I suggest you avoid doing any blocking operations in the GUI event thread.